# AdMob test Ads show, real ones don't (tried everything)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, integration

I have a Unity game app, I wanted to update my app, after publishing to play store (the update), I noticed Ads are not working anymore. Although the app works perfectly well with test ads, it doesn't work when test Ad Unit Ids (and test App ID) is switched with my Ad unit IDs and App ID.

I did make sure to wait a couple of days to allow Google/AdMob systems to figure out the changes and start showing Ads, but no result, it simply doesn't work.

I think I've got every bit of the code in (GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.cs file) right because it's barely tweaked from how it was.

As far as AndroidManifest file goes, however,  I am not sure because I don't know how its suppose to be or how it works. I did try to change it a bunch of times (as some guides / Q/A say so and have suggestions on this topic), but then it would make my project unbuildable, and other errors would pop up, or other it simply wouldn't fix the project. 
What I am giving you now works 100% well (when there is test Ad Ids), still work but won't show any Ad when there is my Ad IDs.

*Note: this is a Unity project Android Game,*
*here I've used `******` to cover my ID, in the real file there is the proper ID*

### **This is AndroidManifest code** taken from `Assets/Plugins/Android/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">



<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />       <!-- MM: added this to skip permissions in start, Success! this works -->
</activity>


    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb23423*******" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider23423******" android:exported="true" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**this part is taken directly from GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.CS, (with a few tiny bits of my tweaks),** so, it has to be totally ok. If not, then test Ads shouldn't show up.

---

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

// Example script showing how to invoke the Google Mobile Ads Unity plugin.
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;
    public InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;
    private float deltaTime = 0.0f;
    private static string outputMessage = string.Empty;

    public static string OutputMessage
    {
        set { outputMessage = value; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {

        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string appId = "ca-app-pub-******"; 
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string appId = "ca-app-pub-*******";
        #else
        string appId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        MobileAds.SetiOSAppPauseOnBackground(true);

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);

        // Get singleton reward based video ad reference.
        this.rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

        // RewardBasedVideoAd is a singleton, so handlers should only be registered once.
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;

        }


        public void Update()
        {
        // Calculate simple moving average for time to render screen. 0.1 factor used as smoothing
        // value.
        this.deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - this.deltaTime) * 0.1f;
        }

// MM: this is the UI we don't need  from tutorial 
/*
        public void OnGUI()
        {
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();

        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.LowerRight;
        style.fontSize = (int)(Screen.height * 0.06);
        style.normal.textColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        float fps = 1.0f / this.deltaTime;
        string text = string.Format("{0:0.} fps", fps);
        GUI.Label(rect, text, style);

        // Puts some basic buttons onto the screen.
        GUI.skin.button.fontSize = (int)(0.035f * Screen.width);
        float buttonWidth = 0.35f * Screen.width;
        float buttonHeight = 0.15f * Screen.height;
        float columnOnePosition = 0.1f * Screen.width;
        float columnTwoPosition = 0.55f * Screen.width;

        Rect requestBannerRect = new Rect(
        columnOnePosition,
        0.05f * Screen.height,
        buttonWidth,
        buttonHeight);
        if (GUI.Button(requestBannerRect, "Request\nBanner"))
        {
        this.RequestBanner();
        }

        Rect destroyBannerRect = new Rect(
        columnOnePosition,
        0.225f * Screen.height,
        buttonWidth,
        buttonHeight);
        if (GUI.Button(destroyBannerRect, "Destroy\nBanner"))
        {
        this.bannerView.Destroy();
        }

        Rect requestInterstitialRect = new Rect(
        columnOnePosition,
        0.4f * Screen.height,
        buttonWidth,
        buttonHeight);
        if (GUI.Button(requestInterstitialRect, "Request\nInterstitial"))
        {
        this.RequestInterstitial();
        }

        Rect showInterstitialRect = new Rect(
        columnOnePosition,
        0.575f * Screen.height,
        buttonWidth,
        buttonHeight);
        if (GUI.Button(showInterstitialRect, "Show\nInterstitial"))
        {
        this.ShowInterstitial();
        }

        Rect destroyInterstitialRect = new Rect(
        columnOnePosition,
        0.75f * Screen.height,
        buttonWidth,
        buttonHeight);
        if (GUI.Button(destroyInterstitialRect, "Destroy\nInterstitial"))
        {
        this.interstitial.Destroy();
        }

        Rect requestRewardedRect = new Rect(
        columnTwoPosition,
        0.05f * Screen.height,
        buttonWidth,
        buttonHeight);
        if (GUI.Button(requestRewardedRect, "Request\nRewarded Video"))
        {
        this.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
        }

        Rect showRewardedRect = new Rect(
        columnTwoPosition,
        0.225f * Screen.height,
        buttonWidth,
        buttonHeight);
        if (GUI.Button(showRewardedRect, "Show\nRewarded Video"))
        {
        this.ShowRewardBasedVideo();
        }

        Rect textOutputRect = new Rect(
        columnTwoPosition,
        0.925f * Screen.height,
        buttonWidth,
        0.05f * Screen.height);
        GUI.Label(textOutputRect, outputMessage);
        }
*/
//MM: end of UI, can hide it again later. 

        // Returns an ad request with custom ad targeting.
        private AdRequest CreateAdRequest()
        {
        return new AdRequest.Builder()

        //.AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
        //.AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")

        //MM: these filters are not required
        /*      
        //.AddKeyword("game")
        //.SetGender(Gender.Male)
        //.SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
        //.TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
        //.AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
        */

        .Build();
        }

        public void RequestBanner()                                     //MM: this funciton was made from "private" to "public" so it can be accessed from within other scripts
        {
        // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused"; 
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-*******";         
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-*******";
        #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Clean up banner ad before creating a new one.
        if (this.bannerView != null)
        {
        this.bannerView.Destroy();
        }

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        this.bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);

        // Register for ad events.
        this.bannerView.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleAdLoaded;
        this.bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleAdFailedToLoad;
        this.bannerView.OnAdOpening += this.HandleAdOpened;
        this.bannerView.OnAdClosed += this.HandleAdClosed;
        this.bannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleAdLeftApplication;

        // Load a banner ad.
        this.bannerView.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
        }

        public void RequestInterstitial()           //MM: changed this from "private" to "public" so it be accessible from other places as well
        {
        // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-********";        
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-*********";
        #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Clean up interstitial ad before creating a new one.
        if (this.interstitial != null)
        {
        this.interstitial.Destroy();
        }

        // Create an interstitial.
        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

        // Register for ad events.
        this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleInterstitialLoaded;
        this.interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
        this.interstitial.OnAdOpening += this.HandleInterstitialOpened;
        this.interstitial.OnAdClosed += this.HandleInterstitialClosed;
        this.interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;

        // Load an interstitial ad.
        this.interstitial.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
        }

        private void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
        {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID                                                             string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-***********";         
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-*********";
        #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        this.rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest(), adUnitId);
        }

        public void ShowInterstitial()
        {
        if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
        this.interstitial.Show();
        }
        else
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("Interstitial is not ready yet");
        }
        }

        private void ShowRewardBasedVideo()
        {
        if (this.rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
        this.rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        }
        else
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("Reward based video ad is not ready yet");
        }
        }

        #region Banner callback handlers

        public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
        }

        public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + args.Message);
        }

        public void HandleAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");
        }

        public void HandleAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");
        }

        public void HandleAdLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeftApplication event received");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Interstitial callback handlers

        public void HandleInterstitialLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleInterstitialLoaded event received");
        }

        public void HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
        "HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad event received with message: " + args.Message);
        }

        public void HandleInterstitialOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleInterstitialOpened event received");
        }

        public void HandleInterstitialClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleInterstitialClosed event received");
        }

        public void HandleInterstitialLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleInterstitialLeftApplication event received");
        }

        #endregion

        #region RewardBasedVideo callback handlers

        public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded event received");
        }

        public void HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print(
        "HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad event received with message: " + args.Message);
        }

        public void HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened event received");
        }

        public void HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted event received");
        }

        public void HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed event received");
        }

        public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
        {
        string type = args.Type;
        double amount = args.Amount;
        MonoBehaviour.print(
        "HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded event received for " + amount.ToString() + " " + type);
        }

        public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication event received");
        }

        #endregion
}
```

---

And finnally this part is where I request for Ads inside my game controler.

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Facebook.Unity;

public class GameControll : MonoBehaviour {

    public GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript GoogAdsTemp;           //MM: this is a referance to the GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript for ads/example

    public static int coin;
    public static bool pause;
    public Text coine, distance;
    public Text goCoin, goScore, goBScore, lamlCount;
    public GameObject MainMenuPanel, GameOverPanel, powerPanel, SaveLifePanel;
    private AudioListener al;
    private int lcoin, lCount;
    private float timerl = 0;
    private bool lifesave = false;
    public GameObject saveButton;
    private Image sl;
    public static bool SaveMe = false, loadS;
    public static bool showAd = false;
    private bool changeScorecolor;
    private float cc = 0;


    public static bool GoogleMobileAdsStarted = true;                   //MM: this is just a testing bool, I created, that's it.



    void Start()
    {
        GoogAdsTemp.Start ();                   //MM: this is to initiate GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript // sort of to link with ad engine.

        coin = 0;
        changeScorecolor = false;
        distance.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
        pause = false;
        showAd = false;
        GoogleMobileAdsStarted = true;              //MM: added this
        al = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<AudioListener>();
        al.enabled = true;

        if (ProtectedPrefs.HasKey("Coins"))
        {
            lcoin = ProtectedPrefs.GetInt("Coins");
        }
        else {
            lcoin = 0;
        }
        GetLamp();
        sl = saveButton.GetComponent<Image>();

//MM: created bellow from here 
        if (GoogleMobileAdsStarted == true)
        {
            Debug.Log ("We are loading ads now, serving from start method");
            GoogAdsTemp.RequestBanner ();               //MM: this is to show banner ads
            Debug.Log ("1st ad from start just served");
            GoogAdsTemp.RequestBanner ();               //MM: this is to show banner ads
            Debug.Log ("2nd ad from start just served");

            GoogAdsTemp.RequestInterstitial();              //MM: added this, interstitial after gameover (to load it)
            Debug.Log ("We just requested for an Interstitial load, from Start");
        }
//MM: created up to here

    }





    void Update()
    {

//MM: created bellow from here 
        if (GoogleMobileAdsStarted == false)
        {
            Debug.Log ("We are turning GoogleMobileAdsStarted to = true now and serving an ad");
            GoogleMobileAdsStarted = true;
            this.GoogAdsTemp.RequestBanner();               //MM: this is to show banner ads
            Debug.Log ("Ads just served in from Update method.");
        }

        //MM: this is to check whether or not interstitial is loaded, if not, then it loads it again.
        if (GoogAdsTemp.interstitial == null)
        {
            GoogAdsTemp.RequestInterstitial ();             //MM: added this, interstitial after gameover (to load it)
            Debug.Log ("We just requested for another Interstitial load, now from update");
        }
//MM: created up to here



        if (lifesave == true && Controller.iDie && !loadS && !SaveMe)
        {
            showAd = false;
            SaveLifePanel.SetActive(true);
            timerl += Time.deltaTime;
            sl.fillAmount -= Time.deltaTime / 1.8F;
            if (timerl >= 1.8F)
            {
                timerl = 0;
                sl.fillAmount = 1;
                SaveLifePanel.SetActive(false);
                Invoke("GameOver", 0.5f);
                loadS = true;
            }
        }

        if (itemAbsorb.getLamp) GetLamp();
        coine.text = coin.ToString();
        distance.text = Controller.Distance.ToString("00000000") + "0";
        if (Controller.Distance > 10 && Controller.Distance > ProtectedPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore") && !changeScorecolor) {
            cc += Time.deltaTime;
            if (cc < 1)
            {
                distance.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
            else if (cc > 1 && cc < 1.5f)
            {
                distance.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
            }
            else if (cc > 1.5f && cc < 2)
            {
                distance.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
            else if (cc > 2 && cc < 2.5f)
            {
                distance.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
            }
            else if(cc>2.5f){
                distance.color = new Color(1f, 0.92f, 0.016f, 1f);
                cc = 0;
                changeScorecolor = true;
            }

        }
        if (Controller.iDie && ProtectedPrefs.GetInt("mLamp") < 1)
        {
            MainMenuPanel.SetActive(false);
            Invoke("GameOver", 0.5f);
        }
        else if (Controller.iDie && ProtectedPrefs.GetInt("mLamp") > 0 && !lifesave)
        {
            MainMenuPanel.SetActive(false);
            lifesave = true;
            loadS = false;
        }
    }

    public void SaveLife()
    {
        SaveLifePanel.SetActive(false);
        ProtectedPrefs.SetInt("mLamp", lCount - 1);
        Controller.iDie = false;
        SaveMe = true;
        lifesave = false;
        GetLamp();
        MainMenuPanel.SetActive(true);
        timerl = 0;
        sl.fillAmount = 1;
    }

    public void GetLamp()
    {
        if (ProtectedPrefs.HasKey("mLamp"))
        {
            lCount = ProtectedPrefs.GetInt("mLamp");
        }
        else {
            lCount = 0;
        }
        itemAbsorb.getLamp = false;
        lamlCount.text = lCount.ToString();

    }

    private void GameOver()
    {
        showAd = true;

        GoogAdsTemp.ShowInterstitial();                 //MN: added this, interstitial after gameover (to show it)
        Debug.Log ("We just served it, hopefully");


        GameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
        powerPanel.SetActive(false);


        ProtectedPrefs.SetInt("Coins", lcoin + coin);
        goCoin.text = "Coins: " + coin.ToString();
        goScore.text = "Score: " + Controller.Distance.ToString("f0") + "0";
        if (Controller.Distance > ProtectedPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore"))
        {
            ProtectedPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", Controller.Distance);
        }
        if (ProtectedPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
        {
            goBScore.text = "Best Score: " + ProtectedPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore").ToString("f0") + "0";
        }
        else
        {
            goBScore.text = "Best Score: " + Controller.Distance.ToString("f0") + "0";
        }
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            #if !UNITY_EDITOR
                StartCoroutine (Facebook.Unity.FBManager.SetScore ());
            #endif
         }
    }

    public void isPause() {
        pause = true;
        al.enabled = false;


    }

    public void isContinue()
    {
        pause = false;
        al.enabled = true;
    }

    public void isRestart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("main");
    }

    public void isMainMenu()
    {
        pause = false;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("menu");
    }
}
```

---

**I really really appreciate your help in regards!**

Comment: If it's test ad, it shows 100% of the time, and perfectly well, if its my Ad Unit ID, it doesn't show anything, 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you were able to upload the app like that. The **package** field in the Manifest should match your app's package name (com.mycompany.myawesomegame). You should be able to update the package name in player settings in Unity. Admob will also need to know the correct package name.

Edit: I might actually be a crazy person. That value might get overridden. Have you tried downloading the app from the store on another device?

Comment: You mean "Bundle Identifier" (I am using Unity 5.5.5)? I looked at it, it was different than what Manifest is saying in above, so I changed AndroidManifest made it same as it was saying under Bundle Identifier (com.pqr.xyz), was hoping it will get fixed, buid the apk and installed on my phone, but still I am not getting any real Ads,

Do you think anything else could also be wrong with my AndroidManifest file? @nameless

Comment: Yes, I've downloaded the app from the store on another device as well, it doesn't show the ads,

Comment: Anyone out there to help me? Really appreciate any help

Comment: Sorry. This has happened to me before, too, but I don't remember a clear solution. Some sanity checks: Is your app linked in Admob (App Settings)? Does it contain Ad units (Banner/interstitial/etc)? Do the App IDs match what is placed in your project?

Comment: Yes, it's linked in AdMob and has Ad Units (all of them), and yea the App IDs match what is placed in my project. Basically, everything is as it should be. Test Ads won't show if they are not. (anyway, I double and quadruple checked everything already).

But still, no ads show up,